# Data Type Overhead

Tags: memory

Whenever a program implements specific data types, there must be a header and some sort of system to detect what data type a variable is. Does this dramatically affect the required space to store smaller data types such as bytes and booleans, or the time required to change or apply operations to them? Are there any techniques commonly used to minimize this overhead for the smaller variables?

Answer (score 0):

In compiled languages there is generally not such overhead. At compile time, there is a need for such information but not beyond that.

However, some Object Oriented Languages have type descriptors for Object (but not  integers and booleans).